# quoting {print $NF} inside layers of single and double quotes?

Tags: perl, tcsh

Stuck trying to figure out how to single quotes withing single quotes within double quotes.  Here's what I'm trying to do....

From perl, I want to run a system command that...
- does an ssh into a remote machine
- executes 'uptime' and then plucks the last field out of that (avg load last 15 min).

```
\#\!/usr/bin/env perl   
my $cmd = "ssh othermachine 'uptime | awk '{print $NF}'' > local_file.dat";   
system($cmd);
```

Of course this won't run ...

```
% ./try.pl

Missing }.
%
```

Missing "}" ???   Looks like it's interpreting the $NF} as a var? I tried escaping the {} chars with no luck. I tried escaping the $, no luck. I tried a space before the }, no luck but different msg (Undefined variable).

c-shell BTW and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the following to be `ssh`'s second argument:

```
uptime | awk '{print $NF}'
```

To do that, you simply placed single quotes around it. But that doesn't work because it contains single quotes.

---

You want to build a string that contains `$NF`, but you did it as follows:

```
"...$NF..."
```

That will place the value of (non-existent) Perl variable `$NF` in the string.

---

Do it step by step.

- Static:

  1. Remote command:

     ```
      uptime | awk '{print $NF}'
     ```
  2. Local command:

     ```
     ssh othermachine 'uptime | awk '\''{print $NF}'\''' >local_file.dat
     ```
  3. String literal:

     ```
     my $local_cmd = q{ssh othermachine 'uptime | awk '\''{print $NF}'\''' >local_file.dat}
     ```
- Dynamic:

  ```
  use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

  my $remote_cmd = q{uptime | awk '{print $NF}'};
  my $local_cmd = shell_quote('ssh', 'othermachine', $remote_cmd) . ' >local_file.dat';
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

It doesn't complain, and it produces a number, but it's the wrong number :-(.  I did thes commands in rapid succession...
    
    atlhen-vdi3074:/home/dgauthie/WStat/bin[ 440 ] --> cat local_file.dat
0.08
    atlhen-vdi3074:/home/dgauthie/WStat/bin[ 441 ] --> uptime
     15:10pm  up 10 days  6:11,  23 users,  load average: 0.34, 0.38, 0.36
    atlhen-vdi3074:/home/dgauthie/WStat/bin[ 442 ] -->
        
0.08 isn't close to 0.36 (I would have accepted 0.35 e.g.)  Not sure where 0.08 is coming from, but it doesn't look like it's coming from uptime.

Comment: Wait, it's a problem with uptime I think, not your code.

Comment: Oh, no, never mind.  Very stupid mistake.  It's the correct number for the remote machine.  Duhhhhhh !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) and let it do the quoting for you:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($othermachine,
                            remote_shell => 'tcsh');
$ssh->system({stdout_file => 'local_file.dat'},
             'uptime', \\'|', 'awk', '{print $NF}')
  or die "ssh command failed: " . $ssh->error;
```